# return vs. callback in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, nowjs-sockets

Say I write this function...

```
var sayHi = function() {
  return "hi";
}
```

`alert(sayHi());` will return "hi".

Now if I write it this way...

```
var sayHi = function(callback) {
  callback("hi");
}
```

How do I display "hi" with this function?

Based on an example here: http://nowjs.com/doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sayHi(function(msg){
    alert(msg)
});
```

Your new `sayHi` function doesn't return a value, so you have to perform the alert in the callback function.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I was missing something simple here. Everyone pretty much answered at the same time. Wish I had enough rep to vote you all up.

Answer (score 4):

You pass a function to sayHi, so I imagine this:

```
sayHi(alert);
```

Comment: I cannot believe nobody else bothered to point out the most obvious answer.

Comment: Ha! Doh! +1 Can't believe i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

you must have defined some callback function or pass a anonymous function:

```
var sayHi = function(callback) {
  callback("hi");
}

sayHi(function(message){
  alert(message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sayHi(function(value) {
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sayHi(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

You have to invert your thinking process when using callbacks.  Instead of writing the next operation first, you write the next operation last.

Answer (score 0):

Here in example callback is a function. So you should pass function argument.

You may do this in 2 ways:

```
var some_fun = function(some_str) {
    alert(some_str);
}

var sayHi = function(callback) {
  callback("hi");
}

    sayHi(some_fun)
```

or you can pass function when you call it:

```
var sayHi = function(callback) {
  callback("hi");
}

sayHi(function(some_str){
  alert(some_str);
});
```